# Survival analysis on time series data for predictive maintenance

Tags: predictive-modeling, statistics, survival-analysis

I want to train a survival analysis model for predictive maintenance on an asset (confidential, let's say it's a motor). The dataset consists of hourly readings of multiple sensors, the type of motor, motor ID, and whether it failed or not. The dataset is mostly right-censored. As such, we have the following example of a hypothetical dataset:

```
index | time | motor ID | motor type | vibrations | temperature | failed

0,12-01-2023 09.00, 1, type1, 1531564, 19, 0

0,12-01-2023 10.00, 1, type1, 153, 19, 0

0,12-01-2023 11.00, 1, type1, 19235651, 19, 0 # right censored

0,12-01-2023 9.00, 2, type2, 205654684, 19, 0

0,12-01-2023 10.00, 2, type2, 205654684, 19, 0

0,12-01-2023 11.00, 2, type2, 205654684, 19, 0

0,12-01-2023 12.00, 2, type2, 205654684, 19, 1 # failed
```

How would you input this time series data into a Survival Analysis model in Python, such as Cox Proportial Hazard Rate or [GradientBoostingSurvivalAnalysis](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/sksurv.ensemble.GradientBoostingSurvivalAnalysis.html)? I see some examples around that convert this time series into one row with multiple lag features, but this drastically increases the number of features in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You could try time-varying survival analysis if you have long formatted data. One package in python that would allow you to do this is [Lifelines](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Time%20varying%20survival%20regression.html).